# How to pass multiple characters as single character to input value?

Tags: html, character-encoding, fonts, special-characters

When you do something like `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` the button will be named `Submit` (because that's its value).

But what if I'm using font that doesn't have "A" letter attached to "A" position etc.? Instead it uses its own space for characters and uses for instance `\f002` (this is single character). It is vector icons font and I'd like to use one icon as value of submit input.

Using `<input type="submit" value="\f002">` is going to just print `\f002` and not that single icon. How can I convert this?

PS
It works excellent when I use `content: "\f002";` in style.css. It converts this full string to an icon.

PPS
Icons set: http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I made it work. The answer: `&#xf002;` but I don't have explanation - I just remember that some time ago I was struggling with similar issue and adding `x` helped.

Comment: It’s a normal [character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.3.1), except that it’s not. The code position F002 is in the [Private Use Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29), which means that it should not be used except by private agreements. Playing with fonts that use PUA for normal characters is a pointless hazard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd try to add a `class` attribute to the input button?
i.e.: `<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="myClass">`

Take a look at this article: http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_stylish/index.html